Creating a streamlit web app that gets the user email/username from sso log in to the backend
We aim to develop an Azure Web App using Streamlit with integrated Microsoft authentication. The application will restrict access to specific domain groups, allowing authorized users to log in seamlessly without requiring an external Microsoft authentication link.
What we need to do is to provide access only to certain blob folders for each user, so with his email we can filter what the user will be able to see.
The app has delegated permissions for user email and profile.
We have tried many things but nothing really worked out.
The code that we have till now is:
##credential and connections
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
KEY_VAULT_NAME = os.environ.get("KEY_VAULT_NAME")
KV_URI = f"https://{KEY_VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net"
client = SecretClient(vault_url=KV_URI, credential=credential)

##sso
# Azure AD Config
TENANT_ID=client.get_secret("tenantid")
TENANT_ID=TENANT_ID.value
CLIENT_ID = client.get_secret("clientid")
CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID.value
CLIENT_SECRET=client.get_secret("clientsecret")
CLIENT_SECRET=CLIENT_SECRET.value
scope=["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"]

app = PublicClientApplication(
        client_id=CLIENT_ID, 
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}")

result = None 
if not result:
   result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=["User.Read"])

if "access_token" in result:
        access_token = result["access_token"]
        if "id_token" in result:
            id_token = result["id_token"]
            user_info = jwt.decode(id_token, options={"verify_signature": False})
            st.write(f"Welcome, {user_info.get('name', 'User')}!")
            st.write(f"Your email: {user_info.get('preferred_username', 'Not available')}")

        else:
             st.write('No id_token in results')

email = user_info.get('mail', user_info.get('preferred_username', None))


if email:
        if not is_valid_email(email):
            st.error("Invalid email format. Please enter a valid email address.")
        elif email in ALLOWED_EMAILS:
            company_list = df_access['Companies'][df_access['Email']==email].unique()  # Get the list of all unique companies
            if len(company_list) >0:
                st.session_state.logged_in = True
                st.session_state.email = email
                st.session_state.login_time = datetime.now()
                st.success("Login successful!")
                st.rerun()
            else:
                st.error("No companies available for this email.")
        else:
            st.error("Invalid email. Please try again.")
            st.session_state.logged_in = False
    else:
        st.error("Email not found in user information.")




At first we tried this approach with st.query_params(): 

def get_public_keys():
    """Retrieve public keys from Azure AD for validating ID tokens."""
    response = requests.get(DISCOVERY_URL)
    response.raise_for_status()
    jwks_uri = response.json()["jwks_uri"]
    jwks_response = requests.get(jwks_uri)
    jwks_response.raise_for_status()
    keys = jwks_response.json()["keys"]
    print(keys)
    return {key["kid"]: RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(json.dumps(key)) for key in keys}

def validate_id_token(token, public_keys):
    """Decode and validate the ID token using Azure AD public keys."""
    unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    kid = unverified_header["kid"]
    
    if kid not in public_keys:
        raise ValueError("Invalid token key ID (kid).")

    # Decode and validate token
    decoded_token = jwt.decode(
        token,
        public_keys[kid],
        algorithms=["RS256"],
        audience=CLIENT_ID,  # Replace with your Azure app's Client ID
        issuer=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/v2.0"
    )
    return decoded_token

def get_token_from_headers():
    """Extract the ID token from the HTTP headers (Streamlit app)."""
    headers = st.query_params()  # Simulating header extraction
    token = headers.get("id_token", [None])[0]  # Replace with actual header extraction
    if not token:
        st.error("No ID token found in the headers.")
        st.stop()
    return token

public_keys = get_public_keys()

token = get_token_from_headers()

user_info = validate_id_token(token, public_keys)

With no positive outcome.
Also we tried to use Microsoft Graph API that also did not work.

Have you granted admin consent to the delegated permissions.

Do you have User.Read API permission?

To get gets the user email/username, check the below:
Make sure to grant User.Read API permission to the Microsoft Entra ID application:

And make use of below code:
TENANT_ID = "TenantID"  
CLIENT_ID = "ClientID"  
CLIENT_SECRET = "Secret"  

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}"
)

scopes = ["User.Read"]

result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scopes)

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
    print("Token acquired successfully.")  
    
    def get_user_info(access_token):
        graph_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
        }
        
        response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)
       
        print(f"Graph API response: {response.status_code}")  
        print(f"Response content: {response.text}") 
        if response.status_code == 200:
            user_info = response.json()
            print(f"Full User Info: {user_info}")  
            email = user_info.get("mail") or user_info.get("userPrincipalName")
            username = user_info.get("displayName")
            return email, username
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch user data: {response.status_code}")  
            return None, None

    # Get user email and username
    email, username = get_user_info(access_token)

    if email:
        print(f"Welcome, {username}!") 
        print(f"Your email: {email}")  
    else:
        print("Unable to retrieve user details.")  
else:
    print("Failed to acquire access token.")  



In my environment, print() instead of st.write() to print the output to the console. You can use st.write().

Make sure to decode the token in jwt.ms: Welcome! and check if scp claim in the access token contains User.Read permission.

